# li タグの要素が重なってしまう

Tags: html, css

以下のような記述をした時、私の環境だとliタグ一個目と二個目が中央で重なってしまうのですが、これは何が原因でしょうか？

開発環境はWindows 11・VSCode・XAMPPです。

```css
/*============== 汎用設定 ===============*/

.white{
  color: #fff;
  margin: auto;
}
/*============== 背景動画設定 ===============*/

/*header設定*/
#header{
    position: relative;/*h1の中央寄せ配置の起点とするためのrelative*/
    height: 100vh;/*高さを全画面にあわせる*/
} 

#video-area{
    position: fixed;
    z-index: -1;/*最背面に設定*/
    top: 0;
    right:0;
    left:0;
    bottom:0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#video {
    /*天地中央配置*/
    position: relative;
    z-index: -1;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    /*縦横幅指定*/
    width: 177.77777778vh; /* 16:9 の幅→16 ÷ 9＝ 177.77% */
    height: 56.25vw; /* 16:9の幅 → 9 ÷ 16 = 56.25% */
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
}

/*見出し設定*/
h1{
    /*要素の配置*/
    position:relative;
    /*要素を天地中央寄せ*/
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
    /*見た目の調整*/
    color:#fff;
    text-shadow: 0 0 15px #666;
}

/*============== ログインフォーム,サインインの設定 ===============*/
form {
  text-align: center;
}

.login_form_btm {
  padding: 10px 0;
  background-color: #000;
  margin: auto;
  width:250px;
  color:#fff;
}

input {
  width: 200px;
  padding: 3px;
  margin: 5px 0;
}

.id-pass-button {
  border:#fff solid;
  background-color:#000;
  border-radius:5px;
  color:#fff;
}

/*============== タブの設定 ==============*/

.tab{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.tab li a{
    display: inline;
  margin: left;
    background:#ddd;
    margin:0 2px;
    padding:10px 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>ホーム</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/setting.css">
    <link rel="icon" href="img_or_ico/atupoke.ico">
</head>
<body>
    <ul class="tab">
    <li class="tab"><a href="index.html">ホーム</a></li>
    <li class="tab"><a href="login.html">ログイン</a></li>
    </ul>
    <br>
    <header id="header">
        <h1>ホーム</h1>
        <div id="video-area">
        <video id="video" webkit-playsinline playsinline muted autoplay loop>
<source src="video/back.mp4" type="video/mp4">
<source src="video/back.ogv" type="video/ogv">
<source src="video/back.webm" type="video/webm">
<p>動画を再生できる環境ではありません。</p>
</video>
</div>
</header>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: 初心者かどうかは質問に直接関係ないので、毎回の記載は不要です。また、HTML や CSS 周りの話なのでブラウザ関係の情報を書いた方が良さそうです。

Comment: 「私の環境だとliタグ一個目と二個目が中央で重なってしまうのです」とのことですが自分の環境（Windows 10, Chrome 119.0.6045.106）ではそのようにななりません。そこだけを再現できる必要最小限のコードと結果の画像を、質問欄を編集して追記してください。使っているブラウザが何かとそのバージョンも書いてください。

Comment: ありがとうございます！！解決しました！

Answer (score 1):

元のコードでは以下の通り margin (=外側の余白) の上下に `0` を指定しているからだとおもいます。
この部分を適切な値に変更してみてください。

(必要箇所のみ引用)

> ```css
> .tab li a{
> 　    margin:0 2px;
> }
> ```